# Python: Как все элементы многомерного списка преобразовать в строки?

Tags: python, массивы, list

Есть многомерный список, пытаюсь каждый элемент типа int преобразовать в тип str,  далее то что мне нужно по плану и вернуть обратно в int (дата[5] должна сохраниться str всегда(как исключение))

```
z = [[17, 800, 0, 1900, 0, '2021-10-16', 0], [16, 1300, 22, 1600, 44, '2021-10-14', 55]]

z_str = list(map(str, z)) # 1 пробовал

z_str = [str(i) for i in z] # 2 пробовал

print(z_str)
```

ВЫВОД:

```
["[17, 800, 0, 1900, 0, '2021-10-16', 0]", "[16, 1300, 22, 1600, 44, '2021-10-14', 55]"]
```

делает строку из списка в списке .о_О.

Мне нужно вот так:

```
[['17', '800', '0', '1900', '0', '2021-10-16', '0'], ['16', '1300', '22', '1600', '44', '2021-10-14', '55']]
```

Comment: Ну Вы очень близки, объедините оба метода) Вам нужно делать `map` для каждого списка внутри списка, а не для всего списка)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы прошелся двойным циклом с проверкой на тип `int` содержимого. Если выполняется, то преобразуем в строку:

```
z = [[17, 800, 0, 1900, 0, '2021-10-16', 0], [16, 1300, 22, 1600, 44, '2021-10-14', 55]]

z_to_str = [[str(e) if isinstance(e, int) else e for e in row] for row in z]
```

Comment: А если список имеет две тысячи подсписков, разве такой способ не повышает в два раза потребление ресурсов?

Comment: В двух предыдущих постах сложность такая же. В итоге аналогично берется строка из списка, по внутренностям которой проходитесь `list(map(...))`, что эквивалентно в итоге моему варианту. Здесь похожая реализация, но с помощью comprehension. Другой момент, что в предыдущих постах не учли, что нужно, если судить по Вашему посту, только `int` в `str` преобразовывать. В указанных вариантах любой тип будет к строке преобразован.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте такой вариант:

```
z = [[17, 800, 0, 1900, 0, '2021-10-16', 0], [16, 1300, 22, 1600, 44, '2021-10-14', 55]]
z_str = []
for i in z:

    z_str.append(list(map(str, i)))

print(z_str)
```

Циклом "извлекаем" подмножество и уже в нём, непосредственно, преобразуем элементы.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Благодарю, за совет!

Answer (score 3):

Как писал выше asanisimov, нужно объединить два способа:

```
z = [[17, 800, 0, 1900, 0, '2021-10-16', 0], [16, 1300, 22, 1600, 44, '2021-10-14', 55]]

z_str = [list(map(str, i)) for i in z]

print(z_str)
```